# DynamoDB version control using sort keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Anyone that has implemented versioning using sort keys as stated in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html?

Trying to implement this using typescript for building a database with versions of the items. Is there any way of doing this using updateItem or is it a get + put operation needed?

Any sample to get me started or help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

The concept of versioning using sort key involves the creation of a completely new item that uses same Partition Key and different Sort Key.

DynamoDB offers some operations that allow to update values within an object in an atomic way, this use case is perfect for when you have something like a counter or a quantity and you want to decrease/increase it without having to read its value first. - [Docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters).

In the case you're trying to achieve, as mentioned, you are essentially creating a new object. DynamoDB, by itself, doesn't have any concept of versioning and what this pattern does is to cleverly leverage the relation between Partition Key and Sort Key and the fact that a PK can have multiple SK associated with it, to correlate multiple rows of the same table.

To answer your question, if your only source of truth (or data store) is DynamoDB, then yes, your client will have to first query the table to know which was the last version of the item being updated and then insert the new version.
In case you are recording this information elsewhere and are using DynamoDB only to store these versions, then no, one put operation will be enough but again, this assumes you can retrieve this info somewhere else.

In terms of samples, the official documentation of the AWS SDK is always a good start, in your case I assume you'll want to use the Javascript one which you can find [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html).

At a very high level, you'll have to do the following:

- Create an `AWS.DynamoDB()` client.
- Execute a query using the `dynamodb.query()` method and specifying the PK of the item you want to update.
- Go through the items (rows) returned from the previous query and find the one with the bigger version number as SK.
- Put a new item using the `dynamodb.putItem()` method passing an item with the incremented version number as SK and same PK.

Comment: Regarding "Go through the items (rows) returned", you should be able to query for just the last item if you'll make sure it's sortable. I.e. v4 > v3 > v2 etc'

Answer (score 2):

You can do the technique described by Amazon with a read and then a write, or more accurately, a read and then two writes (since they want to update both v0 and a new v4!). Often, you *need* the extra read because you want to build the new version v4 based on data you read from v3 (or equivalently, v0) - but in case you don't need that, the read is **not** necessary, and two writes are enough:

1. You first do an `UpdateItem` to v0 which **increments** the "Latest" attribute, **sets** whatever attributes you want to set in the new version, and uses the **ReturnValues** parameter to ask the update operation to return the new "Latest" attribute.
2. Then you write with `PutItem` the new row for v4 (where 4 is the "Latest" you just read).

This approach is safe in the sense that if two clients try to create two new versions at the same time, each one will pick a different "Latest", and both will appear on the version histories. However, it is not safe in the sense that if the client dies between step 1 and 2, you'll have a "hole" in the version history. However, I don't think there's any implementation of this technique that doesn't suffer from this problem.

After saying this, I want to reiterate what I said in the first paragraph: In most realistic use cases, the new version would be based on the old version, so your code anyway needs to read the old version first, then decide how to change it - and then write it (twice). You can't avoid the read in these cases. By the way, in this case the first write (to v0) would be a conditional update to verify that you only write the new version if the old version is still the same one ("Latest" is the same one you read during the read) - otherwise you'd be basing your modification on a non-current version. This is an example of *optimistic locking*.